# Next.js catch-all / as routing

Tags: javascript, url, routes, next.js, catch-all

First of all, apologies if this is a bit confused. That's because I am also confused. 
I'm pretty new to Next.js and I'm migrating a site over from Gatsby using WP as a headless CMS. I didn't build the original site so I'm inheriting a load of code I'm not familiar with.

I'm using a `/pages/listing/[slug].js` component to generate individual listings for this client. I am fetching paths by querying all the slugs for their listings in `getStaticPaths`, and using the slug to query the db to get data for the page using `getStaticProps`. All good so far.
Only issue right now is I've been told the client wants to retain their urls as they currently are - eg `listing/experience/location/product-name-here` (where `product-name-here` is the slug I fetched from the CMS), but I have only figured out how to do `listing/product-name-here`.

My failed approaches so far have been to:

- Change the component to `[...slug].js`, but I am getting moaned at for the slug not being an array. Even if I change it into an array manually when I am fetching the static paths, because only the slug is being fetched, I am still not using the correct url.
- Use the `as` prop on the `Link` component. It sends me to the link that I want now, but I get a 500 error. If I enter the url manually using the `href` prop (ie. `listing/product-name-here`), the page loads correctly, but with the wrong url.

I have wondered if there is some way to access the URL, but the only thing I have come across is so far is `useRouter` and since that's a hook I am unable to use it outside of the component itself.

Feel free to ask any questions if this is unclear. I have left code snippets out because I feel like my approach is fundamentally wrong rather than this being an annoying error I am getting.

**Edit**
The problem was eventually solved by having `fallback` set to `true`, and setting a hell of a lot of optional chaining for anything handling API related data - as well as empty defaults on all props. My gut feeling is still that this is not the correct 'Next' way to handle this, but the project was migrated over from Gatsby and kind of shoehorned in so I just needed to get it working.

Comment: You need to create a file: `./pages/listing/experience/location/[slug].js` , basically directories inside directory. Please refer: [Nested Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction#nested-routes)

Comment: @brc-dd thanks for the comment, but this is not what I'm going for. I did actually find a way to get the paths from the CMS, and ```getStaticPaths``` is getting the array of values to create the route for the catch all ```[...slug].js```, but ```getStaticProps``` is not seeing the ```params.slug``` being passed to it. So I can't query the db for the page content I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pages/listing/[...slug].js` as filename, and then return from the `getStaticPaths` an object like this:

```
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { slug: ["path1"] } },
      { params: { slug: ["path2"] } },
      { params: { slug: ["deeper", "path"] } }
    ],
    fallback: false
  };
```

This means that following addresses are working:

- listing/path1
- listing/path2
- listing/deeper/path

Then you can access the slug as an array in `getStaticProps` from the context `context.params.slug`. That would contain `["path1"]`, `["path2"]` or `["deeper", "path"]` depending on the page visited.

You can try it out in the sandbox below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-microservice-lu2jl?file=/pages/listing/%5B...slug%5D.js

Comment: I've taken a look at this, but I think it might be referring to the ```router``` object from the ```useRouter``` hook. The path appears in an array in ```getStaticPaths```, but ```getStaticProps``` just doesn't get called. I have seen a ticket from the Vercel support team saying that falsey values don't get passed to ```getStaticProps```, but I've checked the paths object being passed and it's definitely truthy.

If you can provide any more insight I would be grateful.

Comment: My apologies, the answer was wrong, I made a working codesandbox and wrote the answer again.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I ended up removing all calls to ```getStaticProps``` and rendering anything complex on the page, and it turns out that the array was able to be passed to ```getStaticProps```. However it seems the issue is that api calls are returning undefined and **then** returning the data. So the app is immediately seeing undefined and throwing an error instead of getting the information it needs. Have you come across this issue, and will using ```Promise.all``` be effective?

Comment: Sounds like you would need some logic to show a spinner for example while loading? You can check if it's undefined in the start of your render function, and show some loading text or spinner until the data is available.

Comment: Again, this is probably me being inexperienced, but is this actually useful for static content? My understanding is that everything is already (supposed to be) there, and there's no need for any loading spinners since nothing is being rendered on the client side. Thanks once again, I appreciate your time and patience and input.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought you removed the getStaticProps, my bad. Could you add parts of the code to help solve this? Or accept this answer and open a new question for the new issue?

Comment: I'll close as the issue keeps appearing to change and this thread is less and less relevant.

Comment: I think I might have run into the solution for getting the undefined first and then the data. Read this thing about fallback property, if it's set to true, it works like that, if it's set to blocking, then it'll wait for the data on first try: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required

Comment: That was a super useful part of the documentation I hadn't come across before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Next 13+**

if you are using an App router then `getStaticPaths` is replaced with `generateStaticParams`.

here is how it looks like,

```js
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ slug: ['1'] }, { slug: ['2', '3'] }]
}
```

for more check out [next js doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#dynamic-paths-getstaticpaths)